# SQL query to retrieve conversations records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 SQL tables: `Conversations` and `Users`. Conversations has many Users and Users has many Conversations. So I have the join table `Conversations_users` that has 2 fields: `conversation_id` and `user_id`.

Now I know the ids of some users and I want to retrieve the conversations where all these users are in the same conversation. Someone can help me?

Comment: What did you try?Where is your code?

Comment: post you schema, and since you store here only id i think you want to retrieve the comments for the conversation, so you need the join on 3 tables

Comment: You really need 3 tables for this, conversations, messages, users,

Comment: Note that we sometimes use the term 'threads' for online 'conversations'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to filter the `Conversations_users` table by user, group by conversation and then filter the resulting groups for those that contain the requisite number of (distinct) users:

```
SELECT   Conversations.*
FROM     Conversations JOIN Conversations_users USING (conversation_id)
WHERE    Conversations_users.user_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT Conversations_users.user_id) = 3
```

If `(conversation_id, user_id)` is guaranteed to be unique in `Conversation_users` (e.g. it is that table's `PRIMARY KEY`), one can use `COUNT(*)` instead of the (expensive) `COUNT(DISTINCT Conversations_users.user_id)`.